# How to add kconfig / defconfig for ddk_submodule

Tags: bazel

I know that ddk_module supports kconfig and defconfig.
However, when I implement the ddk_submodule, config for the conditional_srcs of the ddk_submodule
does not work even if I add it to kconfig and defconfig of ddk_module.

ex)

```
    ddk_submodule(
        name = rule_name,
        srcs = module_srcs,
        out = "{}.ko".format(module.name),
        conditional_srcs =  {
            "CONFIG_TEST_1": {
                True: [
                    "mytest/test1.c",
                ]
            },
        },
    )

    ddk_module(
    ..
        kconfig = "test_Kconfig",
        defconfig = "test_defconfig",
    ..
    )
    
    [test_Kconfig]
    config TEST_1
        default y
        bool "config test"
    
    [test_defconfig]
    CONFIG_TEST_1=y
```

Thanks